# Problema con objeto en Typescript

Tags: array, typescript, poo

Estoy practicando TS y quiero pasar un array de strings (cada string tiene el par nombre propiedad en la forma "nombre=propiedad") a un objeto, y funciona pero me muestra un error si quiero imprimir una sola propiedad:

```
var array = ["nombre=jorge","apellido=balsamo","dni=45869202"]
var obj = new Object();

array.forEach(index => {
  Object.defineProperty(obj,index.split("=")[0],{ value: `${index.split("=")[1]}`, writable: true})
})

console.log(obj.nombre)
```

"Property 'nombre' does not exist on type 'Object'." ese error me tira, pero en JS esto funciona bien, supongo que es por el tipado fuerte pero no se como solucionar esto, podria agregar algo como una interfaz para que reconozca que el objeto contiene dichas propiedades pero si el array fuese mas grande y tuviese mas propiedades que solo 3 no se como implementarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

al objecto `obj` no le definiste de forma explicita la propiedad *nombre* de forma que el intellisense no sabe que `obj` tiene esta propiedad por lo que te arroja error, para "saltarse" este caso siempre puedes acceder a las propiedades de los objetos de la siguiente forma:

```
console.log(obj['nombre'])
```

Comment: entiendo muchas gracias